# How to keep memory of text file in C++?

Tags: c++, fstream

Recently, I have written a shape generator project to display the shape of triangle and rectangle in C++. The output will be on the screen and text file. But I have a question, how do I actually let the text time memorise all the shapes that are chosen by the user? For example, the shapes are always stored in textfile..if first time running I chose 3 times ..those 3 selected objects should remain in the file when i exit the program.the next time i chose 2 times …and exit the program..the textfile should have 5 objects in total.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void printTriangle(int n)
{
    cout << "\t~~Triangle Generator~~" << endl;
    cout << "\n\tEnter Height of Triangle: ";
    cin >> n;
    int k = 2 * n - 2;
    cout << "\n";
    // open a file in write mode.

    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("shape_generator.txt");

    // character to be printed
    char ch = 'O';

    // outer loop to handle number of rows
    // n in this case
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        // inner loop to handle number spaces
        // values changing acc. to requirement
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            cout << " ";
            outfile << " ";
        }

        // decrementing k after each loop
        k = k - 1;

        // inner loop to handle number of columns
        // values changing acc. to outer loop
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            // printing stars
            cout << ch << " ";
            outfile << ch << " ";
        }

        // ending line after each row
        cout << endl;
        outfile << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

void printRectangle(int height, int width)
{

    cout << "\t~~Rectangle Generator~~" << endl;
    int i, j;
    /* Input number of rows from user */
    cout << "\n\tEnter Height of Rectangle: ";
    cin >> height;
    cout << "\n\tEnter Width of Rectangle : ";
    cin >> width;
    cout << "\n";
    // open a file in write mode.
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("shape_generator.txt");

    /*Iterate through N rows*/
    for (i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
        /*Iterate over columns*/
        for (j = 1; j <= width; j++) {
            /*Print star for each column*/
            cout << "O";
            outfile << "O";
        }

        /* Move to the next line/row */
        cout << "\n";
        outfile << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    // close the opened file.
    outfile.close();
}

void exit()
{
    cout << "\n\tThank You For Using Our Services. Have A Nice Day!" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int height;
    int width;
    int option;

    do {
        system("color ED");
        cout << "\t" << string(35, '_') << "\t\n";
        cout << "\n\tWelcome to Shape Generator Service!\n";

        cout << "\t" << string(35, '_') << "\t\n\n";
        cout << "\t* * * * * * * * * * * * *" << endl;
        cout << "\t*                       *" << endl;
        cout << "\t*\t1.Triangle \t*" << endl;
        cout << "\t*                       *" << endl;
        cout << "\t*\t2.Rectangle\t*" << endl;
        cout << "\t*                       *" << endl;
        cout << "\t*\t0.Exit     \t*" << endl;
        cout << "\t*                       *" << endl;
        cout << "\t* * * * * * * * * * * * *" << endl;
        cout << "\n\tEnter Option: ";
        if (cin >> option) {
            switch (option) {
            case 1:
                system("cls");
                system("color D7");
                printTriangle(n);
                break;

            case 2:
                system("cls");
                system("color CF");
                printRectangle(height, width);
                break;

            case 0:
                exit();
                break;

            default:
                cout << "\nThe Option is Not Available! Please Try Again.\n" << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "Only Digits are Allowed! Press any key to continue..." << endl;
            getch();
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
            option = 15;
        }

    } while (option != 0);
}
```

Comment: if you write to the file, then it will be remembered

Comment: `c++` will close the file for you in the destructor of `ofstream` so no need to close it yourself.

Comment: You are already writing a file. Perhaps you should explain the issue you are having with the code you have written.

Comment: You probably want to specify that you want to append to the file here: `outfile.open("shape_generator.txt");` related: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are writing a text file and there's `#include <fstream` then I think you mean open the file with append, like:

(example)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    fstream file; //open the file
    file.open("shapes.txt", fstream::out|fstream::app); //set mode as output and append
    string phrase = "Example!\n\n"; //example phrase
    file << phrase;
}
```

Because:

-`fstream::app` is append and will basically add new stuff at the end of the file without erasing the other things

-`fstream::out` is output and is basically meaning you are putting a output and append is a output

-`file <<` will basically add the following parameters to the file

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this has eventually solved my problem! Give you a thumb up!

Comment: I'm glad you liked my answer, it is my first answer ever!!! Also one thing, if you forgot to mark it as answered with that green thing, have a nice day! :D